# combine extraReducers with exact same code with redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I created a global error handling slice with redux toolkit. And I would like to refactor it to make it more "dry":

```
const errorsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "error",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    clearError: (state) => {
      state.errors = null;
      state.isOpen = false;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [createScript.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
      const errorArray = Object.values(payload.message).map(
        (key) => key.message
      );
      state.errors = errorArray;
      state.isOpen = true;
    },
    [createScene.rejected]: (state, { payload }) => {
      const errorArray = Object.values(payload.message).map(
        (key) => key.message
      );
      state.errors = errorArray;
      state.isOpen = true;
    },
  },
});
```

The 2 extraReducers do the exact same thing and the payload is normalized. My code works fine as it is.

Is there a way to "combine" the 2 to a single extraReducer (at the end it will be much more)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to combine the two cases reducers into a single case reducer, but you can certainly provide the same reducer function to each. Refactor the duplicate reducer functions into a single common reducer function.

```
const rejectionReducer = (state, { payload }) => {
  const errorArray = Object.values(payload.message).map(
    (key) => key.message
  );
  state.errors = errorArray;
  state.isOpen = true;
};

...

const errorsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "error",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    clearError: (state) => {
      state.errors = null;
      state.isOpen = false;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [createScript.rejected]: rejectionReducer,
    [createScene.rejected]: rejectionReducer,
});
```

## Update

Using the `isRejectedWithValue` Higher Order Function you can compose the thunk actions into a matcher.

```
import { isRejectedWithValue } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const rejectionReducer = (state, { payload }) => {
  const errorArray = Object.values(payload.message).map(
    (key) => key.message
  );
  state.errors = errorArray;
  state.isOpen = true;
};

const errorsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "error",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    clearError: (state) => {
      state.errors = null;
      state.isOpen = false;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      isRejectedWithValue(createScript, createScene), // <-- thunk actions
      rejectionReducer
    );
  },
});
```

Comment: @PixAff Ah, good find. I think I understand how that all works, but the `isRejectedWithValue` higher order function seems to only work if your thunk uses `rejectWithValue` action utility [Handling thunk errors](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors). Looks like `isRejectedWithValue` can compose several actions and place the error on the `payload` property, and return a single action to "listen" to in the extra reducers.

Comment: great answer - that absolutely fixes the problem. Anyhow- I found something in the redux-toolkit docs which might also be a solution: redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities#isrejectedwithvalue But I don't get my head wrapped around it... (my actions are asynchronous thunks with rejectWithValue callback)

Comment: sorry, I accidentally deleted my comment (wanted to edit) - Yes, my actions are asynchronous thunks with rejectWithValue callback

Comment: @PixAff I'm unfortunately not very familiar with the redux-thunk landscape in the redux-toolkit world. I've only just started using redux-toolkit about a month ago, but use redux-observables/rxjs for asynchronous actions. I've updated my answer with what I believe should work (or get close to the mark) (*and time for me to brush up on more docs*).

Comment: Check out the docs on [`builder.addMatcher`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#builderaddmatcher).  You can do `(action) => action.type.endsWith('/rejected')`.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently defining your `extraReducers` with ["Map Object" notation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#usage-with-the-map-object-notation).  You want to use ["Builder Callback" notation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#usage-with-the-builder-callback-notation) instead.

With the builder callback you can match single actions using `.addCase()` but you can also handle multiple actions using `.addMatcher()`.  The first argument of `addMatcher()` is a function that takes the `action` and returns a `boolean` of whether or not it is a match.  Here we want to match all actions that end with `'/rejected'`.

```
const errorsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "error",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    clearError: (state) => {
      state.errors = null;
      state.isOpen = false;
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) =>
    builder.addMatcher(
      // matcher function
      (action) => action.type.endsWith("/rejected"),
      // case reducer
      (state, { payload }) => {
        const errorArray = Object.values(payload.message).map(
          (key) => key.message
        );
        state.errors = errorArray;
        state.isOpen = true;
      }
    )
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you say that Drews answer has any disadvantages?

Comment: Ok, found 2 disadvantages myself: You need (slightly) more code and you need to import the actions.

Comment: Do you think that map object notation is deprecated? And is better to convert to builder callback.....? Thanks

Comment: The map object notion is deprecated at of RTK v1.9.0 and will be removed in v2.0: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/2865

Answer (score 0):

You can use my helpers:

```
import { AnyAction, AsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

enum AsyncActionStatusesEnum {
  PENDING = 'pending',
  FULFILLED = 'fulfilled',
  REJECTED = 'rejected',
}

//eslint-disable-next-line
type GenericAsyncThunk = AsyncThunk<any, any, any>;
type PendingAction = ReturnType<GenericAsyncThunk[AsyncActionStatusesEnum.PENDING]>;
type FulfilledAction = ReturnType<GenericAsyncThunk[AsyncActionStatusesEnum.FULFILLED]>;
type RejectedAction = ReturnType<GenericAsyncThunk[AsyncActionStatusesEnum.REJECTED]>;

// gets a list of asynchronous actions and checks them for the status of at least one === 'pending'
export function isSomeAsyncActionsPending(matchedActionTypes: GenericAsyncThunk[]) {
  return (action: AnyAction): action is PendingAction =>
    matchedActionTypes
      .map(actionType => `${actionType.typePrefix}/${AsyncActionStatusesEnum.PENDING}`)
      .some(actionType => action.type.endsWith(actionType));
}

// gets a list of asynchronous actions and checks them for the status of at least one === 'fulfilled'
export function isSomeAsyncActionsFulfilled(matchedActionTypes: GenericAsyncThunk[]) {
  return (action: AnyAction): action is FulfilledAction =>
    matchedActionTypes
      .map(actionType => `${actionType.typePrefix}/${AsyncActionStatusesEnum.FULFILLED}`)
      .some(actionType => action.type.endsWith(actionType));
}

// gets a list of asynchronous actions and checks them for the status of at least one === 'rejected'
export function isSomeAsyncActionsRejected(matchedActionTypes: GenericAsyncThunk[]) {
  return (action: AnyAction): action is RejectedAction =>
    matchedActionTypes
      .map(actionType => `${actionType.typePrefix}/${AsyncActionStatusesEnum.REJECTED}`)
      .some(actionType => action.type.endsWith(actionType));
}
```

example of use:

```
const fetchCoockBookList = createAsyncThunk(
  'dataSlice/fetchCookBookList',
  async (data: CoockBookParamsType) => await getCoockBook(data)
);

const fetchSeriesList = createAsyncThunk(
  'dataSlice/fetchSeriesList',
  async (data: SeriesParamsType) => await getSeries(data)
);

const isActionsPending = isSomeAsyncActionsPending([
    fetchDataList,
    fetchSeriesList,
]);


const dataSlice = createSlice({
    // name, reducers, initialState, ...

    extraReducers: builder => {
    // others builder addCases, addMatchCases, ...

    builder
        .addMatcher(isActionsPending, state => {
            state.error = null;
            state.isLoading = true;
          })
        // addMatchers for fullfield, rejected
    }
})
```